# Reduce collision hit between objects

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using rigidbody on my object but the when the collision occurs between two objects, it flies off. I want the collision to be minimum. What should I change in my rigidbody settings?

Comment: there are several ways to reduce the collision to minimum. for example by increasing/decreasing the Mass. increasing the drag value will also help.
Plus you can also assign Physic Material(https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) to the rigidbody.

Answer (score 1):

In the collider component add a physics material and in the physics material scriptable object change the bounciness and the same for your other object with which it is colliding.